# What are the different kind of alerts that questions can have?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when i go to a question on SO it says "Locked by..." Another one is "closed as exact duplicate by"  I was just curious as to how many different alerts like this a question can have on SO.

Comment: Are you asking for a list of all the things that can be done to a question? Or just the "negative" ones?

Comment: The [faq for stack exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) has items for protected, locked, closed and deleted questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question statuses with messages are:

- Closed, which include *Exact Duplicate*, *Off Topic*, *Not Constructive*, *Not a Real Question*, *Too Localized*, *General Reference*, and *Noise or Pointless*. The last two only exist on a few sites. Closing disallows new answers.
- Locked, which prevents all activity.
- Deletion.
- Bounty, which allows one to select from several messages as well as write a custom message to be appended.
- Protection, which disallows new answers from users with less than 10 reputation from that site.
- Migration from another site (migrations to are covered by *Closed*).
- Moderator post notices such as insufficient explanation, current event, citation needed.

It is possible for a question to have at least 5 messages (migration from, mod notice, closed, locked, deleted) and perhaps 6 (above + protected), but a bounty cannot be active on a closed question.

As for what each of these states exactly are, there's an extensive [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) here on Meta that you can browse.

Comment: Also migration to/from another site and post notices (insufficient explanation, current event, citation needed).

Comment: Deletion isn't final at all. Any post can be undeleted by moderator or 20K+ members. @Anna - there is also Historical Significance notice, though from my experience it usually does not help and the question get deleted anyway by other moderator who fails to see any significance.

Comment: @Sha Historical significance is one of the notices added with a lock now, so it just falls under that here.